# req.body empty out of nowhere when sending POST with express and node

Tags: node.js, express, post

I have a node app on heroku that is using express to act as a REST API.

On thursday and friday of last week, it was working just fine, when i would post using REST Easy through firefox. I hope on Saturday morning and the request would no longer send the data.

I can see the data in the payload of the request, but it never makes it to the request body.

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

let app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

let router = express.Router();

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json(req.body);
});

app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

All i get back is an empty object, which i believe is the by product of the `bodyParser.json()`

I am sending it as form data using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and i have even tried checking to make sure it wasn't parsed twice, which would cause the key to be the body data using

```
try {
    req.body = JSON.parse(Object.keys(req.body)[0])
} catch (err) {
    req.body = req.body
}
```

I am completely stumped at this point, any thoughts?

Comment: are you using postman to send the data or html form

Comment: i have been using https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/rest-easy/

Comment: does req.body provides key value data

Comment: It was before, was destructuring like so

`let {username, libID} = req.body;`

Comment: Looks like it was something with that addon, just stopped working overnight. Had to download chrome and use Advance Rest Client, and that showed the data coming through. Thanks for jumping on the question @p0k8_

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was something with that addon, just stopped working overnight. Had to download chrome and use Advance Rest Client, and that showed the data coming through. Thanks for jumping on the question @p0k8_

Comment: use postman https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

better then Advance Rest Client,
make sure to upvote the comments, if you find anyone useful